# Write SQL code similar to a stored procedure inside my MVC project

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am looking into rewriting a stored procedure that returns an output parameter inside my code. Why I am doing this is because I am wanting to have a local stored procedure instead of having to call the stored procedure from MSSQL.

Is this possible? If so, then how?

Comment: Of course it's possible, a stored procedure is just code logic and that logic should be reproducible in almost any other language. I doubt you'll find documentation that tells you exactly how to do it though as every situation is going to be different.

Comment: That's what I thought, and that's great to hear that I am not going down a rabbit hole to a dead end. I'll get started coding and see where I get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked into LINQ to Entities and started to realize that there is so little control of the queries. I need to find more definitive info, but from working with real stored procedures and using multiple queries, having an actual stored procedure would be more efficient with large amounts (meaning hundreds of thousands) of records because of pre-built items included with MSSQL and SPs. I am using this question as a reference for a future project when we want to have small-scale data being transferred from the front end of the site instead of using stored procedures.

This link is what I used to write my raw SQL code. I am using the primitive calls so I can return string variables. 
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/raw-sql-query-in-entity-framework.aspx

**A rough draft of my stored procedure looks like this:**

I am using `//` for legibility purposes when viewing this answer. Please use `--` when using this code.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSomething] 
        @FirstName  varchar(25),
        @LastName   varchar(25),
        @UserID     varchar(25),
        @RentalManID    varchar(25),
        @BranchAreaNum  varchar(25),
        @ReturnVal varchar(1) = '0' output

WITH RECOMPILE
AS
BEGIN   

SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @CheckTblUserAdded varchar(25)
DECLARE @CheckTblUser varchar(25)
// ReturnVal = 0 means it failed to add user to table
// ReturnVal = 1 means it succeded in adding user to table
// ReturnVal = 2 means the user has already been added to the table

// Search for user inside tblUserAdded
SELECT @CheckTblUserAdded = [Window ID] FROM dbo.tblUserAdded WHERE [Window ID] = @UserID AND 
                                                           [Rentalman ID] = @RentalManID AND 
                                                           [BranchAreaNum] = @BranchAreaNum AND 
                                                           [FirstName] = @FirstName AND
                                                           [LastName] = @LastName
// Search for user inside tblUser
SELECT @CheckTblUser = [UserID] FROM dbo.tblUser WHERE [UserID] = @UserID AND
                                                           [RentalManID] = @RentalManID

// Add new user if not found in either tblUserAdded or tblUser
// and if the users windows id and rentalmanid are not the same
IF (ISNULL(@CheckTblUserAdded, '') = '') AND (ISNULL(@CheckTblUser, '') = '') AND (@UserID <> @RentalManID)
BEGIN
    // Do something here
    SELECT @ReturnVal = '1' // as success
END
// Record attempt of adding an existing user
ELSE
BEGIN
    // Do something here
    SELECT @ReturnVal = '2' // already exists
END

SELECT @ReturnVal

END
```

**This is my raw SQL version of this inside my controller:**

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="Window_ID,Rentalman_ID,BranchAreaNum,FirstName,LastName")] tblUserAdded tbluseradded)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (tbluseradded.Window_ID == tbluseradded.Rentalman_ID)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The user should already have access since the user's Windows ID and RentalMan ID are the same. Contact IAUnit for help on the issue");
            }
            else
            {
                // Rewrite stored procedure in form of raw SQL
                string returnVal = "0";
                // This will check to see if a user has already been added to tblUser and tblUserAdded
                string checkTblUserAdded = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SELECT [Window ID] FROM dbo.tblUserAdded WHERE " + 
                    "[Window ID] = '" + tbluseradded.Window_ID + "' AND " +
                    "[Rentalman ID] = '" + tbluseradded.Rentalman_ID + "' AND " +
                    "[BranchAreaNum] = '" + tbluseradded.BranchAreaNum + "' AND " +
                    "[FirstName] = '" + tbluseradded.FirstName + "' AND " +
                    "[LastName] = '" + tbluseradded.LastName + "'").FirstOrDefault<string>();
                string checkTblUser = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SELECT [UserID] FROM dbo.tblUser WHERE " +
                    "[UserID] = '" + tbluseradded.Window_ID + "' AND " +
                    "[RentalManID] = '" + tbluseradded.Rentalman_ID + "'").FirstOrDefault<string>();
                // Add new user if not found in either tblUserAdded or tblUser
                if (checkTblUser == null && checkTblUserAdded == null)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("We can add the user now! We did it!");
                    returnVal = "1";
                    // Do something here
                }
                else
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("This user already has access");
                    returnVal = "2";
                    // Do something here
                }
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The return value is: " + returnVal);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Please break here!");
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(tbluseradded);
    }
```

I am sure there is a better way of coding this by putting the actual raw SQL in a Data Access Layer, but I am using this for information purposes only.